# Can a Vue component access the original expression of a prop?

Tags: vue.js

The `props` array allows a Vue component to declare what property *values* it receives. Is there a way to determine what the original *property expression* was?

For example, for this Vue component:

```
Vue.component( 'my-component', Vue.extend( {
    template: '<output>The answer is {{value}} but what is the question?</output>',
    props: [ 'value' ]
} ));

new Vue( {
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            theQuestion: '42'
      }
    }
} );
```

and this HTML:

```
<div id="app">  
    <my-component v-model="theQuestion"></my-component>
</div>
```

how could the Vue component access the text string `theQuestion` as contained in the `v-model` attribute? Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/oznz8a4z/

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#props. You can access much more on the prop than just the value using object notation instead of the array notation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Using the object notation, I see `required` and `default` and `validator` on prop, but again all these apply to the value. Could you please provide an example of accessing the original expression?